# Vue 3. Предназначение фреймворка

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Можно ли на Vue 3 собрать сайт, состоящий из нескольких страниц, корзины?
И для чего Vue на практике нужно? Почему бы не работать на чистом JS? Или по сути то же самое в плане результата, но фреймворк удобнее, производительнее и лучше поддерживается со временем?

Answer (score 2):

> для чего Vue на практике нужно?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#What-is-Vue-js

> Можно ли на Vue 3 собрать сайт, состоящий из нескольких страниц

https://router.vuejs.org/ru/

> Почему бы не работать на чистом JS

Представь что ты получил с сервера данные и теперь их нужно отобразить в нескольких местах: кнопках, шапке, в меню... при этом отображать в зависимости от условий и состояния приложения

Значит тебе придаться найти старую(ранее созданую) разметку -> удалить ее -> проверить все условия -> создать новый блок и правильно вставить, а если от этого блока зависят и другие блоки(например шапка рендерит и меню и тд) то обновить нужно и их.

Это очень сложно, это сложно читать поддерживать или изменить в будущем.

> Или по сути то же самое в плане результата, но фреймворк удобнее,
> производительнее и лучше поддерживается со временем?

Vue(и другие реактивные фреймворки) предлагают просто сделать так(псевдокод):

**state.data = newData;**

А все изменения которые нужно сделать Vue найдет сам и обновит, при том очень эффективно.

Другие преимущества:

- Можно писать js, html, css(scss) в одном файле
- уже из коробки проект будет настроен на сборку не нужно возиться со сборщиками.
- реактивные стили
- множество плагинов.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ к комментариям

Разделим сайты на два типа:

1. Статические - те которые не измениться или почти не измениться(блоги, форум, сайт с документацией, визитка, ...) и пользователь максимум может лайк нажать.
2. Динамические(или сайты-приложения) - те которые получают постоянно данные для отображения или в которых юзер может менять состояния(соц-сети, биржа,...)

Для первых Vue(или другой реактивный фреймворк) может быть избыточен. Для вторых почти неизбежен.

Comment: Ну про "Почему бы не работать на чистом JS" немного некорректно. Всё описанное можно и без Vue сделать. Тут скорее основное преимущество в том, что это фреймворк, и все необходиые вещи уже давно сделали за тебя. Никто не запрещает на чистом JS сделать то же самое (и разработать параллельно свой фреймворк), но это лишнее время.

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, согласен, к тому же vue написан на чистом js(так или иначе) Но нужно учитывать что vue уже много лет и у него тысячи пользователей, так что это еще один плюс к надежности.

Comment: Спасибо, чуваки!

Comment: "Представь что ты получил с сервера данные" - если сервер пришлёт готовую разметку, то ничего сложного не будет и можно вообще без JS-кода обойтись

Comment: @andreymal, нельзя, сказано об обновлении в нескольких местах и в зависимости от состояния клиента. Можно добавить что в обновлении данных БЕЗ перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: @ValeraKvip ну ладно, пусть будет десяток строчек JS-кода, которая делают ajax-запрос и выполняют `document.body.innerHTML = response` чтобы обновить всю страницу целиком без перезагрузки :)

Comment: @andreymal, это не эффективно, можно открыть любую биржу и увидеть что начальная загрузка может занять несколько секунд, но потом биржа обновляет каждые 100мс(или чаще) кучу данных. Так что будет слайдшоу. "чтобы обновить всю страницу целиком без перезагрузки" а состояние клиента сохранять и читать из бд? или на сервер отправлять. К тому же любые API вернут json, а не html(и зачем мне вставлять чужой html на страницу, если сервер не мой). Есть и такой подход, конечно, в каких то вордпресах. Под каждую задачу свой инструмент.